# live chat plugin for a website

Tags: chat, jquery

Firstly sorry, this is bit of a vague question.

I am trying to research on different live chat plugins available out there to add into a website (e.g testwebsite.com).

The plugin will need to have a real person behind, ie not a bot. Also the people behind the chat needs staffs of the company (TestWebsite).

Also it will be ideal if there is a way someone can resume the chat when they change device. We were thinking maybe provide them with a reference number and they can use that to resume previous chat. This maybe impossible, I'm not sure. Hence why i am trying to get more info on it.

Can you please recommend a some plugins that may do the job?

---

Update
After some research i found that there were quite a few systems that do this.
https://www.zendesk.co.uk/product/pricing/

https://www.livechatinc.com/pricing/

https://www.zoho.eu/salesiq/pricing.html

https://www.olark.com/pricing

Comment: Can you detail what exact requirements do you have for this plugin?

Comment: https://www.zoho.eu/salesiq/pricing.html found this on my research. This seems to most of the bits i require.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are asking for something like this

[Intercom messaging](https://www.intercom.com/drlp/live-chat/kvmaqg?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=990998822&keyword=intercom%20launcher%20wordpress&ad_collection=48338172239&ad=234267937576&match_type=b&network=g&ad_pos=1t1&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIv9HWiIHi3AIV2IRwCh26nQxFEAAYASABEgLdkfD_BwE)

It has wordpress plugin also and generally used in website to talk to their potential customers visiting their sites.